# Read and return the apps installed on the device

Tags: android

I am a new developer in android and am struggling to develop my application, because I need a function or something to read and return the apps installed on the device, if anyone can help me I thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
//getting label name which is install
            PackageManager p = mContext.getPackageManager(); 
            List<ApplicationInfo> info = p.getInstalledApplications(0);
            for(int i=0;i<info.size();i++){
                String label = p.getApplicationLabel(info.get(i)).toString();
                System.out.println("LABEL:"+label);
            }
```